# How to add filter in the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, widget, filtering

Code is below

```
from io import StringIO
text = '''Product,Count
Pen,10
Pencil,15
Book, 10'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))
df.plot(x="Product", y="Count", kind="bar")
```

[image]

- How to add filter in the graph itself that user has to privilege to select which `product` has to display in the graph and `count` also let's say if `count > 11` then only Pencil has to appear.
- Is there any alternate way also there to do this?
- IF one column is date column can we do filtering with date column also

Comment: you can take a look at Matplotlib's Widgets: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/widgets_api.html

Comment: Here's a demo on how to add a Slider: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## matplotlib.widgets

As suggested in the comments, one way to do this is using the `matplotlib.widgets` and you can read more about them [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/widgets_api.html), though for the actual implementation, I found most useful their examples of [Sliders](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html) and [Check buttons](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/check_buttons.html). Using your minimal example, the simplest adaptation I could come up with (that looks ok) would look like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, CheckButtons

text = '''Product,Count
Pen,10
Pencil,15
Book,10'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(
    nrows = 2,
    ncols = 2,
    figure = fig,
    wspace = 0.3,
    hspace = 0.6,
    height_ratios = [2,1]
    )
ax.set_position(gs[0,:].get_position(fig))

axMinCount = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
axProducts = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])

labels = ('Pen', 'Pencil', 'Book')
minimum = 5
actives = [True, True, True]

df.loc[actives & (df['Count'] >= minimum)].plot(
    x = 'Product', y = 'Count', kind = 'bar', ax = ax, legend = False
    )

sMinCount = Slider(axMinCount, 'Min Count', 0, 20, valinit = minimum, valstep = 1)
cProducts = CheckButtons(axProducts, labels, actives)


def update(val):
    minimum = sMinCount.val
    df_filtered = df.loc[actives & (df['Count'] >= minimum)]
    if not df_filtered.empty:
        df_filtered.plot(
        x = 'Product', y = 'Count', kind = 'bar', ax = ax, legend = False
        )
    else:
        ax.cla()

def check(label):
    index = labels.index(label)
    actives[index] = not actives[index]
    df_filtered = df.loc[actives & (df['Count'] >= minimum)]
    if not df_filtered.empty:
        df_filtered.plot(
        x = 'Product', y = 'Count', kind = 'bar', ax = ax, legend = False
        )
    else:
        ax.cla()
    
sMinCount.on_changed(update)
cProducts.on_clicked(check)

plt.show()
```

With various filtering settings, the result looks like this:

[image]

---

## ipywidgets (Jupyter notebook)

I'd suggest also trying `ipywidgets`, which have a much nicer user interface than `matplotlib.widgets`. You can read more about [Using Interact](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Using-Interact). Using your minimal example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from ipywidgets import interact

text = '''Product,Count
Pen,10
Pencil,15
Book,10'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))

# This is a wrapper of the function that follows, providing the interactive input
@interact(MinCount = (0, 20, 1), pen = True, pencil = True, book = True)
# Note that in the core function below, you can set the starting values
def plotter_fun(MinCount = 0, pen = True, pencil = True, book = True):   
    # Filter the data using the interactive input
    df_filtered = df.loc[(pen, pencil, book) & (df['Count'] >= MinCount)]
    # If all data has been filtered out, announce it
    if df_filtered.empty:
        print('No data to show.')
    # Otherwise plot
    else:
        df_filtered.plot(x = 'Product', y = 'Count', kind = 'bar')
```

The result with various filtering settings looks as follows:

[image]

Of course, there are many options for configuring the layout etc.

> This solution is designed to work primarily in **Jupyter Notebook**,
> though if you'd like to embed this functionality somewhere else, you
> can read about [Embedding Jupyter Widgets in Other Contexts than the
> Notebook](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html#embedding-jupyter-widgets-in-other-contexts-than-the-notebook).

Comment: upwoting for nice explanation, if one column is date column can we filter with `date` also

Comment: @aysh I don't see anything pre-made for `matplotlib.widgets`, so you'd have to make something custom for dates if you'd use that module. In comparison, `ipywidgets` has a [Date picker](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Date-picker) widget that's made just for that!